# Words that end with "mt"

Tags: word-choice

Is *dreamt* the only English word that ends with "mt"?

Comment: It probably depends how you define 'word', but *dreamt* + its derivatives (*undreamt*, and possibly *daydreamt*) are the only ones, unless you include the name Klimt.

Comment: No need for a down vote. How many honestly knew the fact before this question was posted?

Comment: Also posted here: http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question98856.html

Comment: Although a little crass language here's the wiki answer: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_dreamed_the_only_English_word_ending_with_mt

Comment: If you're talking about pronunciation, I pronounce *exempt,* *tempt,* *unkempt*, and similar words with 'mt'. (And so do a lot of other people, since *Merriam-Webster* pronunciation gives the 'p' as optional.)

Answer (score 3):

If you exclude abbreviations and allow for possible variants of the same word, then [yes](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2amt&scwo=1&scwo=1&sswo=1).

You can also confirm this via [regexdict](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/) with the search string, `.*mt$`.